# get one item from an array of name,value JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this array:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({name:"k1", value:"abc"});
arr.push({name:"k2", value:"hi"});
arr.push({name:"k3", value:"oa"});
```

is it possible to do get the value or a specific element by knowing the name ?

something like this:

```
arr['k2'].value
```

or

```
arr.get('k1')
```

Comment: Have you try this ? : `arr.k1`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Arrays are normally accessed via numeric indexes, so in your example `arr[0] == {name:"k1", value:"abc"}`. If you know that the `name` property of each object will be unique you can store them in an object instead of an array, as follows:

```
var obj = {};
obj["k1"] = "abc";
obj["k2"] = "hi";
obj["k3"] = "oa";

alert(obj["k2"]); // displays "hi"
```

If you actually want an array of objects like in your post you can loop through the array and return when you find an element with an object having the property you want:

```
function findElement(arr, propName, propValue) {
  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i][propName] == propValue)
      return arr[i];

  // will return undefined if not found; you could return a default instead
}

// Using the array from the question
var x = findElement(arr, "name", "k2"); // x is {"name":"k2", "value":"hi"}
alert(x["value"]); // displays "hi"

var y = findElement(arr, "name", "k9"); // y is undefined
alert(y["value"]); // error because y is undefined

alert(findElement(arr, "name", "k2")["value"]); // displays "hi";

alert(findElement(arr, "name", "zzz")["value"]); // gives an error because the function returned undefined which won't have a "value" property
```

Comment: There is a small bug in your findElement function. The it does not use the index variable (i). it should be: if (arr[i][propName] == ... and in the return

Comment: this is really neat :)

Answer (score 82):

I know this question is old, but no one has mentioned a native solution yet.  If you're not trying to support archaic browsers (which you shouldn't be at this point), you can use `array.filter`:

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({name:"k1", value:"abc"});
arr.push({name:"k2", value:"hi"});
arr.push({name:"k3", value:"oa"});

var found = arr.filter(function(item) { return item.name === 'k1'; });

console.log('found', found[0]);
```

```html
Check the console.
```

You can see a **[list of supported browsers here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)**.

In the future with ES6, you'll be able to use **[array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**.

Comment: Bear in mind: `filter` does not allow mutation of the array's contents, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 43):

**Find one element**

To find the element with a given name in an array you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
arr.find(item=>item.name=="k1");
```

Note that `find` will return just one item (namely the first match):

```
{
  "name": "k1",
  "value": "abc"
}
```

**Find all elements**

In your original array there's only one item occurrence of each name.

If the array contains multiple elements with the same name and you want them all then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which will return an array.

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({name:"k1", value:"abc"});
arr.push({name:"k2", value:"hi"});
arr.push({name:"k3", value:"oa"});
arr.push({name:"k1", value:"def"});

var item;

// find the first occurrence of item with name "k1"
item = arr.find(item=>item.name=="k1");
console.log(item);

// find all occurrences of item with name "k1"
// now item is an array
item = arr.filter(item=>item.name=="k1");
console.log(item);
```

**Find indices**

Similarly, for indices you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (for finding the first match) and `filter` + `map` to find all indices.

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({name:"k1", value:"abc"});
arr.push({name:"k2", value:"hi"});
arr.push({name:"k3", value:"oa"});
arr.push({name:"k1", value:"def"});

var idx;

// find index of the first occurrence of item with name "k1"
idx = arr.findIndex(item=>item.name == "k1");
console.log(idx, arr[idx].value);

// find indices of all occurrences of item with name "k1"
// now idx is an array
idx = arr.map((item, i) => item.name == "k1" ? i : '').filter(String);
console.log(idx);
```

Answer (score 19):

To answer your exact question you can get the exact behaviour you want by extending the Array prototype with:

```
Array.prototype.get = function(name) {
    for (var i=0, len=this.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (typeof this[i] != "object") continue;
        if (this[i].name === name) return this[i].value;
    }
};
```

this will add the get() method to all arrays and let you do what you want, i.e:

```
arr.get('k1'); //= abc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you're asking natively with an array, but javascript objects are hashes, so you can say...

```
var hash = {};
hash['k1'] = 'abc';
...
```

Then you can retrieve using bracket or dot notation:

```
alert(hash['k1']); // alerts 'abc'
alert(hash.k1); // also alerts 'abc'
```

For arrays, check the [underscore.js library](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) in general and the [detect method](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#detect) in particular.  Using detect you could do something like...

```
_.detect(arr, function(x) { return x.name == 'k1' });
```

Or more generally

```
MyCollection = function() {
  this.arr = [];
}

MyCollection.prototype.getByName = function(name) {
  return _.detect(this.arr, function(x) { return x.name == name });
}

MyCollection.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.arr.push(item);
}

etc...
```

Comment: "You can't do what you're asking natively with an array" is incorrect, you can add **arr.get('k1')** by modifying the Array prototype.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({name:"k1", value:"abc"});
arr.push({name:"k2", value:"hi"});
arr.push({name:"k3", value:"oa"});

var found = arr.filter(function(item) { return item.name === 'k1'; });

console.log('found', found[0]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about jquery so can't help you with that, but as far as Javascript is concerned you have an array of objects, so what you will only be able to access the names & values through each array element. E.g `arr[0].name` will give you `'k1'`, `arr[1].value` will give you `'hi'`.

Maybe you want to do something like:

```
var obj = {};

obj.k1 = "abc";
obj.k2 = "hi";
obj.k3 = "oa";

alert ("obj.k2:" + obj.k2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach which I have used is

```
var found = arr.find(function(element) {
         return element.name === "k1";
 });

//If you print the found :
console.log(found);
=> Object { name: "k1", value: "abc" }

//If you need the value
console.log(found.value)
=> "abc"
```

The similar approach can be used to find the values from the JSON Array based on any input data from the JSON.