# Function to find object in array using one or more conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a vanilla javascript solution to find an object using one or more conditions.

Ideally, I'd like to use a similar syntax as lodash.find and a reusable function that can take one or more conditions:

```
_.find(products, {code:"BLK")
_.find(products, {code:"BLK", sale: false})
```

In my case, I'm looking for one object, so I'd prefer `find` over `filter`.

```js
const products = [
  {
    title: "Shirt",
    color: "Black",
    code: "BLK",
    sale: true
  },
  {
    title: "Better Shirt",
    color: "Black",
    code: "BLK",
    sale: false
  },
  {
    title: "Blue Shirt",
    color: "Blue",
    code: "BLU",
    sale: false
  }
]

// Lodash find using multiple conditions
console.log(_.find(products, {code:"BLK", sale: false}))

// Find all using one condition
console.log(products.filter(product => product.color === 'Black'))

// Find single with multiple conditions
console.log(products.find(product => product.color === 'Black' && product.sale === false ))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**How can I emulate the functionality of _.find from lodash in simple, vanilla js?**

Comment: Have a look at the lodash sourcecode?

Comment: Here's the answer in gist: https://gist.github.com/SephReed/82eb00e44075576d4f778bfd71817c76

Why would marking a question as "unclear" make it unanswerable?  If someone can answer it, it's obviously clear enough.

Comment: Should be closed as a duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/215552)

Comment: Or [get one item from an array of name,value JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7075485/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the lodash behaviour by using `Array.prototype.find` and inside the callback you check each key and value of the individual objects in your supplied array with the filter object you pass as the second argument `obj` using `Array.prototype.every()`:

```js
const products = [
  {
    title: "Shirt",
    color: "Black",
    code: "BLK",
    sale: true
  },
  {
    title: "Better Shirt",
    color: "Black",
    code: "BLK",
    sale: false
  },
  {
    title: "Blue Shirt",
    color: "Blue",
    code: "BLU",
    sale: false
  }
]
function find(arr, obj){
  return arr.find((ele) => {
    return obj && Object.keys(obj).every(key => ele[key] === obj[key]);
  }) || arr[0];
}

// Lodash find using multiple conditions
console.log(find(products, {code:"BLK", sale: false}));
console.log(find(products, {title:"Blue Shirt", sale: false}));
console.log(find(products, undefined));
console.log(find(products, {}));
console.log(find(products, {title:"Better Shirt", sale: true}))
```